# Getting response from json - how to use in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Should be quite an easy one - I'm getting a dictionary in a .cs file and sending it back to .js as a json, using the following:

```
//return our value
return Response.AsJson(MyDictionary);
```

The .js file picks it up here:

```
App.Server.postJSON("/api/stuff/getmyresponse/" + self.id() + "/" + WhatToGet)
    .then(function (r) {
        console.log(r);
    });
```

This returns the following response, which is expected:

```
Object {3214368: 939000, 3214369: 701000, 3214370: 581000, $id: "100"}
```

(though the id isn't really necessary)

Now, what I'm wondering is, in the .js file, how do I start messing around with this data, or at least setting another variable to it and doing stuff like looping through and running some calculations?

Comment: have u tried this: assign json to any var and use that variable

for (i = 0; i < Object.length; i++) { 
    text += Object[i] + "<br>";
}

Comment: I can assign the json to another var, such as MyRes, but using MyRes.length or MyRes[0] returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You already have what you need in the 'r' object:

`App.Server.postJSON("/api/stuff/getmyresponse/" + self.id() + "/" + WhatToGet)
    .then(function (r) {
        console.log(r.3214368); // 939000
        console.log(r.3214370); // 581000
    });`

Comment: your code wont work

Comment: What about r[3214368] ... r[3214370]? if r is a dictionary then you should be able to access the data like that and you'll know whether you're receiving a Json or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job somewhat:

```
var MyRes;
App.Server.postJSON("/api/stuff/getmyresponse/" + self.id() + "/" + WhatToGet)
.then(function (r) {
    MyRes = r;
    for(i in MyRes)
    {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(MyRes[i]);
    }
});
```